# Which is better in MongoDB? Storing a list of members as a array in an object or member group relation collection

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I am building a social app with MongoDB. I have a scenario where I need to store the list of users in a group and their relation to the group. What is the optimized way to store it?
I had come across 2 paths.

- Saving the list of users inside the group collection

  ```
  {
    "groupId":"",
    "admins":[
      "1234","2345","3422"
    ],
    "moderators":[
      "3242"
    ],
    "members":[
      "2354","9865","6747"
    ]
  }
  ```
- saving group id, user id, relation as a list in a separate collection in traditional style

  ```
  {
    "groupId":"1234",
    "userId":"8764",
    "relation":"Admin"
  },{
    "groupId":"0987",
    "userId":"4345",
    "relation":"Member"
  },{
    "groupId":"0987",
    "userId":"3456",
    "relation":"Admin"
  },{
    "groupId":"0987",
    "userId":"7654",
    "relation":"Member"
  },{
    "groupId":"0987",
    "userId":"8765",
    "relation":"Member"
  }
  ```

  My major Queries would be to
- list the members of the group with their relation
- search the members by their starting word
- list the groups a user is a member of

Which approach will be best suited for the above quires.

** excuse me for the json formatting is not accepting in the editor code style.

Comment: When embedding code in list items, indent by 8 spaces instead of 4.

Comment: "search the members by their starting word" - what starting word?

Comment: "What is the optimized way" - it depends on what we're optimizing __for__. Storage efficiency - the first one is better. Queryability - the second one.